# Need to know how to copy lines of text to another file in Java for data formatting program

Tags: java, file-io

I would like some help with a project that I am working on. I want to create a simple program that formats data into a way that is accepting of our database. I am having trouble copying the contents of the main file to the destination file. The program creates the new destination file and it writes the "Gage ID, Date/Time, Precip_1min, Precip/Year" headers in the file but there are no data values copied to the new file. I have tried to look online for some solutions but, I have had no luck in applying these solutions. The main thing that I am concentrating on is copying each line of the main file to the new created file one-by-one then I will work from there. Any assistance is very much appreciated! Here is my code so far. P.S Cowlic105.txt is the file that has the lines of data that I want to be copied.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyDataFormat {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "Cowlic105.txt";
    String fileName2 = "FormDatFile.txt";
    String line = null;
    int x;
    int gageID;
    int precipYTD;



    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {

        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    }


    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is this the file you wish to format? " + fileName + "(0 for no, 1 for yes)");
    x = in.nextInt();

    if (x == 0){

        System.exit(0);

    }
    else if (x == 1){
        System.out.println("Hello there you resumed the program!!!");

        System.out.println("What is the ID of the rain gage? ");
        gageID = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is the value of precipitation YTD? ");
        precipYTD = in.nextInt();

        File destFile =  new File("FormDatFile.txt");

        if(!destFile.exists()){
            try {
                destFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        try {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(destFile);


            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(destFile, true);
            BufferedWriter write2 = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                write2.write(line);
                write2.newLine();

                bufferedReader.close();
                write2.close();
            }




            writer.write("Gage ID,Date/Time,Precip_1min,Precip/Year");
            writer.write("\r\n");                
            writer.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }






}
```

}

Comment: Why are you closing the files as soon as you write the first line?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake I meant to exclude that part from the while loop. But, even after I do that there is no text that is written to the destination file.